# My CtrlHandler does not work when I hide the window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a program in which I shutdown windows this emits a sound. Up to this point all great. But when I hide the window console the program does not emit the sound. Is there some solution for this?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <direct.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sstream>

BOOL CtrlHandler(DWORD fdwCtrlType)
{
    switch (fdwCtrlType)
    {
        
        case CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT:

            Beep(750, 500);
            
            return FALSE;
            
        default:

            return FALSE;
    }
    
}

int main(void)
{
    
//ShowWindow(GetForegroundWindow(),SW_HIDE);//Hide the window console
    
    if (SetConsoleCtrlHandler((PHANDLER_ROUTINE) CtrlHandler, TRUE))
    {
        
        while (1)
        {
            Sleep(500);
        }
    }
    
    else
        printf("\nERROR: Could not set control handler");
}
```

Comment: may beep not allowed without focus? Add OutputDebugString to the handler to see if its being called

Comment: This is horribly broken code. A busy loop that calls Sleep() is bad news.  But you should really scrap all of this. If all you want is a background application, then there's no reason to display a console and then hide it. You don't want a console application at all; you just want a standard Windows desktop application that doesn't ever create a window. Respond to the WM_ENDSESSION message (or WM_QUERYENDSESSION), and beep as desired.

Comment: @Cody Gray to be fair - we have no idea what he is trying to achieve, he has isolated one piece of broken functionality (MVCE as always demanded). I agree the sleep in a while loop is terrible for the finished code

Comment: Sorry for the sleep() another thing was going there.  But is there no way to make it work in console?  It is a simple application.

Comment: The console window doesn't support being hidden.  Realistically, you're kind of lucky the consequences of doing so are so mild. :-)

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: "*You don't want a console application at all; you just want a standard Windows desktop application that doesn't ever create a window.*" - or better, a background service.

Comment: Ah, no, you probably don't want a service. If you create a service, the next question will be, "Why can't my service interact with the desktop?" The vast majority of the time, when you think the answer is to create a service, you have the wrong answer. What Harry means is quite clear: console windows cannot be hidden, so your call to `ShowWindow(..., SW_HIDE)` essentially invokes undefined behavior. You're lucky that the only consequences are that the sound doesn't get played. It could be worse, it could crash your entire system. Don't do it this way; you don't need a console at all!

Comment: I get it, so I´ll do a GUI project to handle WM_ENDSESSION.  Thank you all.